# How can I do a numeric sort of a QStringList in Qt 4.6.2 where QCollator is not available

Tags: c++, sorting, qstringlist

I have seen examples of a numeric sort of a QStringList using QCollator.  Unfortunately, QCollator is not available until Qt 5.2 or later.  I am using Qt4.6.2.

My QStringList only contains integers.

Example QStringList values:

```
20
2
1
3
```

Expected sorted result:

```
1
2
3
20
```

Can anyone provide a simple example C++ source that will provide a numeric sort for a QStringList?

Comment: Could you convert the values to ints and then sort?

Comment: I believe so, but I am unsure of the logic that I should put into the function numericSortCompare in this call:  qSort(mylist.begin(), mylist.end(), numericSortCompare());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Qt documentation for [`QStringList::sort`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/qstringlist.html#sort) suggests to use a QMap for sorting by arbitrary orders. You can build a map and get the sorted strings, like this:

```
QStringList l = QStringList() << "3" << "20" << "2" << "1";
QMap<int, QString> m;
for (auto s : l) m[s.toInt()] = s;
l = QStringList(m.values());
```